# How can I vertically stack left, right, and center columns in that order with reactstrap on md breakpoint?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap to style my three column page

```
<Row>
    <Col md="4">Left</Col>
    <Col md="9">Center</Col>
    <Col md="5">Right</Col>
 </Row>
```

This is the desired layout:

[image: layout]
 The [reactstrap layout docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/) do not give example nor detail how this can be achieved. Currently they are vertically stacked in the same order that they are horizontally ordered left-to-right. I have tried several combinations of className and md props, but have not been able to implement this. How can this layout be achieved with reactstrap?

Comment: I don't know with reactstrap but with css you could set `display: flex` to the parent element and `order: 3` to the 'center column' in `<=md`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution as suggested by [Toni Michel Caubet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533941/toni-michel-caubet)  (.scss)

```
  @media(max-width: 768px) {
    .main-section {
      display: flex;
    }
    .left-col {
      order: 1;
    }

    .center-col {
      order: 3;
    }

    .right-col {
      order: 2;
    }
  }
```

The md breakpoint is 768px. This hardcoded value be replaced with bootstrap breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-4 didn't have the push/pull classes that would have been really helpful... so one solution is to have the `center-Div` twice; Once in the middle for the desktop (which hides on tablet)... and placed in the end for the tablet and smaller sizes (and hidden on desktop)...

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12 d-none d-sm-block col-sm-4 order-2" >CENTER</div>
    <div className="col-12 col-sm-4 order-1" >LEFT</div>
    <div className="col-12 col-sm-4 order-3" >RIGHT</div>
    <div className="col-12 d-sm-none order-4" >CENTER2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.row div:nth-of-type(2){ background:lightpink; }
.row div:nth-of-type(3){ background:lightblue; }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y5rzew)